# Trouble when pushing to Git

Tags: gitlab, push

I am trying to submit my project and I am having trouble pushing to GitLab:

I am receiving this:

To https://gitlab.computing.dcu.ie/prestoa2/2020-ca472-preston-bullock.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.computing.dcu.ie/prestoa2/2020-ca472-preston-bullock.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I have ran the command "git pull" and these errors are on going..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you need to pull from the remote. It is saying that since the time you locally updated your files from remote, some changes have happened remotely, and you cannot push without pulling the most recent changes.